# How to redirect to another area in ASP.NET Web API inside ActionFilter attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I can't find an obvious way to redirect from `Web API` `FilterAttribute` `OnActionExecuting` to the exact same controller under a different area.

Do you know a `Web API` alternative or the right way to redirect to an area as we used to, in MVC with `RedirectToAction`?

I know there's a way to achieve this via resetting the Response object and re-locating the execution context with a Location header like here:

```
var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Found);
response.Headers.Location = new Uri("http://www.google.com");
actionContext.Request = response;
```

I don't know how to specify the area except for explicitly pointing it in the URL.

Basically, here's the place I want to redirect the request to another area, preferably without a full client redirect.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext) {}
```

Comment: What do you mean by an area? Do you mean the Area feature that is available in ASP.NET MVC or you mean to redirect abc.com/api/Values to xyz.com/api/Values?